# Django: Limit user "can change/delete" permission based on one-to-one field

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I added a one-to-one field to extend the Django auth user model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I want to achieve is every Employee has permission to change other Employee objects, but limited to those from the same division they belong to.

I created an 'employee' permission group, with permission to add/change/delete User and Employee objects.

Now each employee has a 'can change' permission for both **all** of the Employee and **all** of the User objects.

I managed to filter the django admin change list on the OneToOneField, so each employee only gets to see the employees from their own division in the change list.

Problem is, if they manually type in the URL for changing a user from another division, they are able to change/delete this user. Likewise they can even change/delete the Superuser (user 1). Navigating to:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/
```

will do the trick.

My idea to fix this was to override the auth user change method, adding a 'division-or-superuser' check, but that seems hacky. I would prefer to limit access to the change URL on the basis of division, but I haven't found a way to achieve this yet.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) in a class based view to force the current user to test against the division of the employee that she/he tries to change.

Assuming that the `change` method is a `POST` method for the following example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class MyView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        ch_user_division = Employee.objects.filter(
            pk=self.request.POST.get('user_id')
        ).values('division')
        return self.request.user.division == ch_user_division
```

Now the class based `MyView` checks if the user is in the same division as the user to be changed.

For further info on how to limit user access: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test

---

**Leaving the following for comment legacy reasons:**

<s>You can use [`ForeignKey.limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument on model definition, which:</s>

> **Sets a limit to the available choices** for this field when this field is rendered using a `ModelForm` or the `admin`.

Try the following:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'division': division}
    )
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thanks: Seems a good solution. But I tried it and it threw a NameError: name 'self' is not defined..

Comment: So I guess limit_choices_to can be used, but it should be elaborated a bit further perhaps: 'employee': **a query set that returns all employees connected to the 'self.division'**? I'll try if I can implement it..

Comment: @DeBaze try omitting the `self.` (as in my edit above) and inform me if it works, because I do not have the setting to test right now.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, no avail (throws 'division not defined'. If I omit self and move the division field def above the user field def, I get that division is not a field of the user object. But 'employee' is, so therefore I came up with my previous comment..

Comment: Even if I would manage to filter the choices (like I tried limiting on the basis of 'date joined') to those from its own division, It has no impact on the 'change/delete' permissions, and that's what I need..

Comment: Thanks. I just started to explore the docs in more or less the same direction, but the link you posted seems a good way to go. I'll try to implement something along the lines you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem using a combination of John's answer above (which I accepted because he pointed me in the right direction), an overriding the existing UserAdmin class change_view method as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class SelectiveUser(BaseUserAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url=''):

    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return super(SelectiveUser, self).change_view(
           request, object_id, form_url, )

    # logic to check using John's method above or another way

    # if check passes, return super(etc....) as above for superuser
    # if not, return 403



admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, SelectiveUser)
```

I did the same for delete_view